# Can I use virtual IP in EC2 VPC?

Tags: amazon-ec2, keepalived, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to get keepalived working in Amazon's EC2 VPC. But I cannot. Is it possible to use virtual IP in EC2 VPC? Or how can I use keepalived in EC2 VPC?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on EC2, since all instances are behind a 1:1 NAT and never interact directly with the public IP address.